# Accessibility issue on expandable list using min-height

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility, uiaccessibility

**Expected requirement:** I need to prevent looping through the inner items (Basically the voice over apps read these) while it's not expanded + Animation.

**What I have done:** I put `display:none` property added to expandable list along with the animation (I used max-height).

**Problem:**: The animation doesn't work when `display:none` nor `visibility:hidden` is used.

**Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qpgyNz)**

**How I need it to be done:**: I would prefer css fix over js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@jazzbrotha gave a solid answer, but I think a few things were overlooked based on the codepen that you provided. Because this is an accessibility related question, I feel compelled to surface other issues that I noticed. I realize that the codepen might not be a 1:1 implementation of the actual interface, so these might not actually be issues. That being said, I've seen these issues a lot in the wild and thought it would be good to surface them.

Accessibility issues that I noticed in the codepen example:

1. Keyboard support: I was unable to activate the section headings to expand/collapse the sections while only using a keyboard. It looks like only a mouse click handler was implemented. This is important for people with visual and physical disabilities, as they may rely on non-mouse input methods.
2. Semantic HTML. Screen reader users learn interaction cues via HTML semantics, and aria-roles will override HTML semantics, thus potentially obscuring functionality. For example

   - `<h2>Section Title</h2>` is announced as "Heading level 2, Section Title". This communicates that this is a section heading and the following content belongs to this section heading. Visual users can quickly scan a page and identify sections and section headings to get a lay of the land and an idea of what options are available, while screen reader users can not. **To accommodate for this, screen readers have a function to list all heading elements on the page and allow users to jump to specific headings**.
   - `<h2 role="button">Section Title</h2>` is announced as "Button, Section Title". This communicates that this is a button and can be activated via click, enter, or space. **This overrides the heading semantics and removes the heading from the list of headings provided by screen readers**.
   - `<h2><button>Section Title</button></h2>` is announced as "Heading level 2, Section Title, Button", **thus communicating that the element is both a section heading, and a button**.
3. The fact that a section has been expanded or collapsed is not communicated by screen readers. To communicate this functionality, you can use the `aria-expanded` attribute as described in the resources below.

An unfortunate side-effect of this is that more js and css will likely be required to fix these issues.

I suggest two things:

1. Read the [accordion pattern that is described the ARIA Best Practices document](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion). This describes all keyboard functionality that should be implemented in JS, as well as the correct HTML semantics and aria attributes that should be used.
2. Read the ['collapsable sections' page on inclusive-components.design](https://inclusive-components.design/collapsible-sections/). This does an amazing job of describing all of the interstices of making accessible collapsable sections.

Both of these resources contain code examples that you can use to not only solve the problem that you are having, but also make the interface more accessible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide `html` elements from assistive technologies such as screen readers you can use `aria-hidden="true"`. And if you want these elements to be ignored while the user navigates the website, you can add `tabindex=-1`.

Then, you can simply change these attributes to `aria-hidden="false"` and `tabindex="0"` when a user clicks i.e. a `button` to allow the screen reader to access the elements.

Let's say you have a list that you want to hide for screen reader users on mobile and for all users on other devices, a simple media query could do the trick. Try using `visability: hidden` if `display:none` is giving you trouble:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  [aria-hidden="true"] { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

You can read more about `aria-hidden` in the official W3C spec [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-hidden). If you want to know more about mobile accessibility, check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/Mobile) MDN article.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My expandable list comes only when it's on the mobile size. Otherwise, it's just a list. 

Do I need to check for width of screen to do that or is there a better solution?

Comment: You can do it with media queries. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I have done the same. But the ultimate objective is to have the accessibility + the animation.
Unfortunately, both visibility/display will take into effect first before the animation. 
Does that make sense?

Comment: But you said that the expanded list is only in mobile, so if the elements are visible in that mode shouldn't the animation work?

Comment: Expandable list :)
You can check the expandable list here - https://www.shell.com/

Bottom of the page.

Once the mobile view comes, you have to press the header to view the expanded version of the children. Hence while doing those, visibility/display will take into effect first before the animation.